# Looking for simple .net example to read a list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, development, .net

I am trying to find a simple example in c# or vb that shows how to connect and then pull in a list and display it in a gridview in asp.net.

We are using SharePoint 2013 with Windows Authentication in claims mode.  The examples I have found on the Internet do not seem to work.

Hoping someone has a simple example or can point me to one that actually works.

The example I found below keeps giving me this error when I run it:

> Unhandled exception at line 23, column 32 in `http://localhost:55984/Default.aspx`
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'RegisterSod' is undefined occurred

**Code**

```
 SharePointList.Lists L = new SharePointList.Lists();
                L.Url = "http://spweb.xyz.com/sites/departments/IT/Lists/IT%20Projects/AllItems.aspx";

                //L.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "YOUR PASSWORD", "YOUR DOMAIN");
                L.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

                System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                string listName = "IT Projects";
                string strReturn = "";
                System.Xml.XmlElement ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
                System.Xml.XmlElement ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
                System.Xml.XmlElement ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

                ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ProjectID\" />" +
                        "<Value Type=\"Single line of text\">ATLAS001</Value>" +
                        "</Eq></Where>";
                ndViewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"ProjectID\" />";
                ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "";

                System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems = L.GetListItems(listName, null, null, ndViewFields, null, null, null);

                foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode X in nodeListItems)
                {
                    strReturn += X.OuterXml;
                }

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(strReturn))
                {
                    //initialize our DataSet
                    ds = new DataSet();

                    //load the StringReader to our DataSet
                    ds.ReadXml(stringReader);
                }

                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
                GridView1.DataBind();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can read data from SharePoint list in your ASP.NET Using **SharePoint CSOM**.

`Client-Side Object Model (CSOM)` is mainly used to build client applications and enable us to access SharePoint Sites that are hosted outside without using web services.

---

**What do you need in order to use CSOM?**

You just need to add the below assemblies as a reference to your solution to be able to work with the `Client Object Model`.

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

These assemblies can be found in the **15 Hive folder**: `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\ISAPI.`

> In case your ASP.net solution will not be hosted on a SharePoint
>   server, you should copy these assemblies first from your SharePoint
>   Server to your solution folder then add it as a reference in your
>   solution, otherwise just add the above reference to your solution

---

**To get a SharePoint List and display it in Gridview via CSOM**

```
ClientContext clientContext = new  ClientContext("http://siteurl");
clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;   
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list name");  
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();  
query.ViewXml = "<View/>";  
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);  
clientContext.Load(list);  
clientContext.Load(items);  
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  

 // create a data table
 DataTable LDT= new DataTable();  
   LDT.Columns.Add("ID");  
   LDT.Columns.Add("Title");  
  //fill datatatable
 foreach(ListItem item in items) 
    LDT.Rows.Add(item.Id, item["Title"]);  
  // set datatable as a dataatsource for grid view
   gr.DataSource = LDT;
   gr.DataBind();
```

**For Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code check**

- [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)
- [SharePoint Client Object Modal (CSOM)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-client-object-modal-csom/)
- [SharePoint Client Object Model: Introduction](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/399156/sharepoint-client-object-model-introduction)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is I think your query value type is wrong - it should be Text

```
 ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ProjectID\" />" +
                        "<Value Type=\"Single line of text\">ATLAS001</Value>" +
                        "</Eq></Where>";
```

should be

```
 ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ProjectID\" />" +
                        "<Value Type=\"Text\">ATLAS001</Value>" +
                        "</Eq></Where>";
```